# how to extract file from a ext4 filesystem data?

Tags: linux, filesystems

i have a XXX.img file.

system.img: Linux rev 1.0 ext4 filesystem data, UUID=XXXX (extents) (large files)

i want to extract some file from it, how?

or XXX.subimg.tgz file

first gunzip it, get subimg file, then as image file.

Comment: Mount it as a `loopback` filesystem.

Comment: oops, how fool am i! i'm not notice img file and iso file are same.Thanks!

Comment: Sometimes we all need more coffee ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
mount -o loop [imgfilename] [path to mount]
```

just like iso file.

Comment: And if I cannot mount? (I'm on a KVM VPS, mount is not possibile at all)

Comment: If you cannot mount, you can use [extfstools](https://github.com/qmfrederik/extfstools)

Answer (score 7):

If you cannot mount (because you don't have root privileges), you can extract the ext4 filesystem data in userspace using [extfstools](https://github.com/qmfrederik/extfstools).

To install it, run:

```
git clone https://github.com/qmfrederik/extfstools
cd extfstools
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
```

To extract all files from `XXX.img` to `savedir`:

```
ext2rd XXX.img ./:savedir
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mkdir -p /mnt/rootfs 
mkdir -p /mnt/disk

mount -o loop rootfs.ext4 /mnt/rootfs 
mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/disk

cp -r /mnt/rootfs/* /mnt/disk

umount /mnt/rootfs
```

Comment: An explanation, why this solves the problem of the OP, would greatly improve this answer.

Comment: While your code may correct as answer But Elaborating what your code does, It can improve the quality of your answer. Checkout the Article : [ How do I write a good answer? ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Please do tell people what the above does as blindly doing this can clear someone's EFI partition causing their system to not boot  (You do not know what sda2 is in the OP's filesystem) explaining as to what sda2 is and to find the same probably using lsblk cmd is a good idea before executing this!